# Check if a View has loaded since midnight

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController that performs a random shuffle on an array and spits out text to a Label (in the `viewDidLoad` method). The problem is that whenever I navigate to the same ViewController it performs the shuffle again and I only need it to shuffle ONCE every day.

So I need to check if this ViewController has been loaded before on the SAME day (i.e. since midnight) and I can then put the shuffle into an if statement. Could I schedule the shuffle at midnight regardless of the app being open or not?

I have looked into setting a boolean to `NSUserDefaults`: something like `hasLoadedSinceMidnight` but then can't work out how to RESET the boolean at midnight.

Comment: That would be one way, but you woould also need to save the state of the items you are "shuffling" and load those as well.

Comment: The array objects are coming from CoreData so they are already saved. The method simply loads them into an array and shuffles them into another array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could implement the AppDelegate's significantTimeChange method:

```
-(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    //tell your view to shuffle
}
```

This method is called every midnight and during significant time changes such as a time zone change. If your app is closed when the event is received, this method will be called when your app is next opened.

More information can be viewed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationSignificantTimeChange:)

An additional way to do the same thing inside of your ViewController instead of in the AppDelegate would be to add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performAction) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and then you can just perform your shuffle operation in the `-(void)performAction;` method of that ViewController.

Comment: +1, or better: subscribe for [`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW44) in the view controller

Comment: That is true. Ill add that.

Comment: I can't find a full list of significant time changes that this method fires - docs just say "For example". It may not be appropriate if users are getting on planes and moving timezones - unless you can surpress that part of the method. The other thing I have seen is that it tends to perform the shuffle but not update the outcome text to `UILabel`..? Can't understand why it would do that. Will the label not update because it's state is already loaded?

Comment: Are you manually changing the label by doing `label.text = @"SomeText"` in your time chnage method?

Comment: Yes it is coming from an array built from `NSManagedObject`. The Log print shows the shuffle being performed and the array being built when the `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` is called in the AppDelegate. But the end of the shuffle method does not - `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [shuffledArray objectAtIndex:0]];`

Comment: I dont know if that is your exact code, but it looks like you are always getting objectAtIndex 0, in which case the text wouldn't change unless your array is actually changing.

Comment: Well this is how I'm doing it: Load the `NSManagedObjects` into a `randomArray`. Shuffle that array and then load it into a second `shuffedArray` with `arrayWithArray:` The Log is printing out a different order of `shuffedArray` each time so the objectAtIndex is definately changing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - major crash and reboot - tested over the last three days and this is definately working now - many thanks! I am changing timeZones later in the month so I will see how it reacts then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a `BOOL`, you could store the date/time (`NSDate`) of the last shuffle.

Then check whether or not it has passed midnight since the last shuffle by comparing the stored date and the current date in the `viewDidAppear`.

See `NSTime` Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And `NSDateFormatter` Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003643

---

UPDATE:

As requested, here is some sample code.  Admittedly, there very well may be better solutions to this, but I believe this code snippet will help you get you past your problem.  What this does is check if there is a date saved using `NSUserDefaults`, then compare with the current date.  If the dates do not match, shuffle the array, then save the current date (again using `NSUserDefaults`).  (I've taken the liberty of making the assumption that time will indeed continue to move forward, so it doesn't check to make sure that `lastSavedDate` is **before** the `currentDate`.)

```
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *lastShuffleDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastShuffleDate"];

// check to see if there is a prior shuffle date
// if there is not, shuffle the array and save the current date
if (!lastShuffleDate) {
    NSLog(@"No object set for 'lastShuffleDate'");

    //[self shuffleMyArray];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"lastShuffleDate"];
    return;
}

// set up the date formatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
NSLog(@"Saved Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastShuffleDate]);

// check to see if the dates are the same by comparing the dates as a string
if (![[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate] isEqualToString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastShuffleDate]]) {
    NSLog(@"Dates are different...!");

    //[self shuffleMyArray];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Dates are the same... (midnight has not passed)");
}

// save the time of the last shuffle
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"lastShuffleDate"];
```

At this point, there is no real reason for you to check the times, but I've included it in case you were curious.

```
// remote dateStyle and set timeStyle to check times
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"Current Time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
NSLog(@"Saved Time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastShuffleDate]);
```

Comment: Interesting - So create a timestamp when the View loads and save that to `NSUserDefaults`? Or just perform a checking method within the view?

Comment: When you shuffle, store the time in NSUserDefaults.  In viewDidAppear (probably the better option for your needs), check the current time against the saved time in NSUserDefaults and determine whether or not midnight has passed.  If it has, re-shuffle and update the NSUserDefaults with the current time to reflect the last shuffle.

Comment: can you give me some example code. I have tried to get this working but can't seem to. `timeIntervalSinceNow` returns the time in seconds between two dates. If the user opens the app at 23:45 and then again at 00:01 only 16mins (960s) has passed. Therefore <86400s have passed but it's the next day. Would a comparison with the `NSDayCalendarUnit` of both dates work? (if they're not == then shuffle)

Comment: @RoshDamunki I've updated my initial answer with some code.  Hope this helps you.  If so, mark it as the correct answer to complete the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay - severe harddrive crash - am currently sorting out. The code looks good to me but I will test on my other machine tmrw. I would probably change `NSLocale` to `currentLocale`...and agreed - as far as I know time going backwards is not posible...otherwise I'd be swaping out my harddrive right about now....!

Comment: No need for apologies.  Yes, use whatever Locale that is needed.  I just chose that because I live in the US.  That said, my suggestion will work, however, you should consider looking into Jsdodgers suggestion above.